# Linux system call table or cheatsheet for Assembly

Tags: c, linux, assembly, system-calls

Does anyone know where to find a summary table or cheatsheet for the Linux system call in Assembly?
I am invoking Linux system calls through the *int 0x80* instruction and I need a quick reference to determine *which register contains which value* from time to time.

Comment: You don't really need one, you just need to know the calling convention (e.g. ebx, ecx, edx, etc. for the 32-bit ABI) and the C argument order.  [What are the calling conventions for UNIX & Linux system calls (and user-space functions) on i386 and x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2535989)  (Plus the Notes section of the man page that comments on any differences between the C interface and the kernel, e.g. for brk/sbrk, or the way `getpriority(2)` encodes the return value to avoid negative values because those mean error.)

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/421750/where-do-you-find-the-syscall-table-for-linux

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[Here's an archive of a really good online reference](https://web.archive.org/web/20200620014648/http://syscalls.kernelgrok.com/) with links to documentation and kernel source code.

Answer (score 2):

The system calls can also be found in /usr/include/asm/unistd.h, which will point you to unistd32.h or unistd64.h

Answer (score 0):

And here's one more that's more easily navigable:
[http://docs.cs.up.ac.za/programming/asm/derick_tut/syscalls.html](http://web.archive.org/web/20160303181025/http://docs.cs.up.ac.za/programming/asm/derick_tut/syscalls.html)

A scripting way to find out for your current machine:

```
ls /usr/share/man/man2 | sed -e s/.2.gz//g | xargs man -s 2 -k  | sort | grep -v 'unimplemented system calls'
```

Credit - [http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~langley/current-system-calls.html](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/%7Elangley/current-system-calls.html)

Comment: Sadly that page is a 404 now…