# looking for a detailed document on Linux System calls

Tags: c, linux, assembly, system-calls

I would like to write my own libc library for x86 Linux for learning purpose. For that, I'd need to call Linux System call in assembly level language. I know how to make system call in assembly on Linux. However, I need to have the complete information on Linux System calls.

I am looking for a detailed document on Linux System call like inputs and output for each system calls. Can anyone please provide me URL/PDF for Linux system call.

For example, for 'sys_socketcall' call, register AX = 102, BX should contain call number for method like create/bind and CX should contain a pointer to 'unsigned long'. Here, I need more information on third parameter (CX).

Comment: `libc` on 8086? You made me faint! Anyways you can start off here-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9506353/how-to-invoke-a-system-call-via-sysenter-in-inline-assembly-x86-amd64-linux

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614995/linux-system-call-table-or-cheetsheet-in-assembly-language

Answer (score 2):

The `socketcall` system call is a special case, so don't rely on this one to learn the general format. Furthermore, it only exist on x86-32, and other platforms use separate system calls for each functions/procedures of the socket operations (with these platforms, there is no `socketcall`, but `socket`, `bind`, and so on).

For the special case which is `socketcall`: it expects `__NR_socketcall` in `eax`, the sub‑function (ex `SYS_SOCKET`, `SYS_BIND`, etc) number in `ebx` and the address of the other arguments in `ecx`. You will have to store an array of as an example, 3 words for the socket operation (creating a socket), store the family in `my_array[0]`, the type in `my_array[1]`, and the protocol (usually 0) in `my_array[2]`, the pass the address of my_array to `ecx` (you don't pass the number of element in `my_array` in any explicit way, it's implied by the socket sub‑function you call).

You may like these documents:

- [sys socketcall: Network systems calls on Linux](http://isomerica.net/~dpn/socketcall1.pdf) [PDF]. Daniel Noé, 2008.
- [INET Sockets Tour: Where is the roots of socket()?](http://www.skyfree.org/linux/kernel_network/socket.html) . 2002.

Now, for other system calls, which are not the `socketcall` exception, you just have to get the reference of the correspoding POSIX function (see [reference](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/ABI/stable/syscalls)), or of the corresponding description of the function from `man(2)` (`man(2)` is section of the manual pages, which is dedicated to the system calls), which you may find as an example, here: [man-pages section 2](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/dir_section_2.html). Then, you have to note the order of the arguments. You will pass the system call number in `eax`, then all other arguments in the same order as described by either `man(2)` or POSIX, to, in order, `ebx`, `ecx`, `edx`, `esi`, `edi`, `ebp` (up to six arguments). The status/result is returned in `eax`.

Note the above applies to Linux on Intel architecture only (you guess other processors have other registers), and also note the system call numbers differs between x86-32 and x86-64.

Answer (score 1):

The best source of information on linux kernel is, surprisingly, its source: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/syscalls.h should contain the needed call definition.

The source of the call itself: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/socket.c#L2366, here you can see how the parameters are handled.

To quickly grep linux source on the net, you can use LXR: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=sys_socketcall.

Comment: Thanks, still I am not sure about each input in "long sys_socket(int, int, int);" API. Through Linux code analysis, I could understand what each input mean here. However, it will require time and I may misunderstood something. So I am looking for detailed information on Linux System call.

Comment: In short, the call may have different number of arguments, depending on `call` argument value. And if you really want to reimplement libc for learning, you'd better choose some modern platform like ARM, finding the kernel version that would run on 8086 is a problem itself.

Comment: Look at line 2349, it contains an array of argument counts, depending on `call` value (which you store in BX register).

Comment: Yes, argument counts depends on call value. Looking for documentation for each argument.

Comment: I guess there should be an document for Standard Library Implementer or system programmers which describes each system calls in detail.

Comment: As you see, links given by other people here are too general and don't address your question directly. And I don't know any documentation better than source (which you are not willing to read).

This function is a kind of mapper, it calls other functions depending on the `call` arg value. For example, in case it equals `SYS_SOCKET`, it calls `sys_socket` with 3 arguments: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/socket.c#L2390. So you should look for `sys_socket` definition to see what they mean, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

- http://www.4shared.com/office/2hhz1YtL/LINUX_System_Call_Quick_Refere.html
- http://seesee.pbworks.com/f/linux.pdf
- http://richard.esplins.org/static/downloads/linux_book.pdf