# Does strace output the actual system calls name or the name of the wrapper functions that perform them?

Tags: linux, assembly, system-calls, glibc, strace

Just asking to confirm that the strace output is the name of system calls and not the name of wrapper functions that perform these actual system calls

Comment: Possibly not; it might have special decoding for the 32-bit x86 `socketcall` system call which (per [looking for a detailed document on Linux System calls](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9940391)) is one kernel function that wraps `socket(2)`, `bind(2)`, `listen(2)`, etc.  But `asm/unistd_32.h` now has entries for `__NR_listen` and so on, so modern 32-bit user-space (oxymoron I know) might these days use those instead of `socketcall`.

Comment: @Peter Cordes, ok but apart from the socketcall ( I'm on x86_64 so it is not relevant anymore ) scenario strace does print the actual system calls names and not the names of the wrapper functions ?

Answer (score 4):

Generally yes; `strace` works by using [`ptrace(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html) to trace system-calls specifically, using `PTRACE_SYSCALL` to ask the kernel to stop at the next system call.

So `strace` only finds out what's going on in terms of the tracee actually entering the kernel, and it decodes based on the register values.  (And on [x86-64 with recent kernels and strace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53456266/can-ptrace-tell-if-an-x86-system-call-used-the-64-bit-or-32-bit-abi), whether user-space used the 64-bit `syscall` ABI or the 32-bit `int 0x80` ABI, which have different call numbers and arg-passing registers but [the 32-bit ABI *is* available in 64-bit code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087730/what-happens-if-you-use-the-32-bit-int-0x80-linux-abi-in-64-bit-code).)

Unlike `ltrace`, it doesn't read user-space library symbol-tables.

---

But `strace` might have special decoding for the 32-bit x86 `socketcall` system call which is one kernel function that wraps `socket(2)`, `bind(2)`, `listen(2)`, etc.  (See [an answer on a related Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9940391/looking-for-a-detailed-document-on-linux-system-calls/15970566#15970566)).

In that case it would maybe still print `listen(...)` instead of the `socketcall(SYS_LISTEN, ...)` raw system call that user-space actually made.  But I haven't checked.

But `asm/unistd_32.h` on my system (Linux kernel 6.7) now has entries for `__NR_listen` and so on, so modern 32-bit builds of glibc might these days use those instead of `socketcall`.  In that case the glibc wrapper name does correspond to the actual system call.  Those call numbers are lower than `__NR_membarrier` which was added in Linux kernel version 4.3, so presumably soon before that.

Comment: While I'm at it, do you know how can I find the complete list of system calls in my linux 6.5.0-14-generic Ubuntu 22.04 x86_64 system along with their numbers ? I downloaded the linux kernel but I'd like to know the correct location...morever is there a way to get this information directly from the terminal ?

Comment: @Kode1000: You already asked that as [How can I get the complete list of system calls supported by my linux system?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77953492).  I commented there to look in `asm/unistd_64.h`, and the duplicates link to  [Where do you find the syscall table for Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/421907) which has details.  The kernel source includes `syscall_64.tbl`, which `asm/unistd_64.h` is built from.