# Signal control in C

Tags: c, unix, concurrency

Is it possible to assure signal invoking order in C? Let's look at the following code:

```
//main.c
int counter;
pid_t pid;

void alrm_handler(int s)
{
    kill(pid, SIGUSR1);
    alarm(1);
    --counter;
    if (counter == 0)
        kill(pid, SIGTERM);
    printf("%d\n", counter);
    fflush(stdout);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    counter = atoi(argv[1]);
    signal(SIGALRM, alrm_handler);
    alarm(1);

    pid = fork();
    if (!pid)
        execl("child", "child", NULL);

    wait(NULL);

    return 0;
}

//child.c
void usr1_handler(int s)
{
    puts("TEXT");
    fflush(stdout);
}

int main()
{
    signal(SIGUSR1, usr1_handler);

    while(1)
    {
        struct timespec T;
        T.tv_nsec = 100;
        T.tv_sec = 0;
        nanosleep(&T, NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Even though I send SIG_USR1 3 times I get an output only 2 times. It seems that SIGTERM has higher priority or something. How is it possible to achieve 3 outputs in this scenario?

Comment: posted code implements a nested/recursive signal handler That is a no-no.  The posted code implements a call to I/O function `printf()` That is a no-no. the first posted code improperly handles the returned value from fork() and seems to expect that the call to execl() will never fail.

Comment: I am not asking about mistakes that this code has (I've omitted some things for simplicity). All I am asking for is a way to ensure that sigterm will not arrive before sigusr1. I think that it is not always possible. SIGTERM might have bigger priority than SIGUSR1 and that's why they arrive in this order.

Comment: most of the programmers to this web site are 'new' and would not know a 'mistake from a chilli pepper.  SO I try to indicate coding problems, outside the scope of the actual question, so the 'new' programmer can learn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One problem with your sample programs, which will affect the order of output, is that you are using buffered-I/O in the signal handlers.  Besides being *unsafe*, the operations do not necessarily complete in the order you expect.

For discussion, see

- [1.2.2.1 POSIX Safety Concepts](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/POSIX-Safety-Concepts.html)
- [Does linux allow any system call to be made from signal handlers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11675040/does-linux-allow-any-system-call-to-be-made-from-signal-handlers)
- [How to avoid using printf in a signal handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891019/how-to-avoid-using-printf-in-a-signal-handler)

Answer (score 2):

The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 6
IEEE Std 1003.1, 2004 Edition:

> The order in which multiple, simultaneously pending signals outside
>   the range SIGRTMIN to SIGRTMAX are delivered to or accepted by a
>   process is unspecified.

Your parent process run so fast that it probably sends `SIGUSR1` and `SIGTERM` before the child being able to receive it, so the child has two pending signals and the order is unspecified (read implementation defined -- any order is possible).