# why does my program crash after fork-exit(0) directly

Tags: c, linux, system

I think that it will not crash. But it crash sometimes.

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
void sig_child(int s)
{
    printf("test here\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    int status = 0;
    wait(&status);
}
int main()
{
    signal(SIGCHLD, sig_child);
    pid_t id = fork();
    if (id < 0)
    {
        printf("fork error.\n");
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    else if (id == 0)
    {
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%d\n", id);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
}
```

my test bash

```
for ((i=1; i<=1000; i++))
do
  ./a.out
done
```

sometimes, the program will crash as the following:

Segmentation fault

you test test it on your computer1

you test test it on your computer2

you test test it on your computer3

you test test it on your computer4

you test test it on your computer5

you test test it on your computer6

Comment: `you test test it on your computer1` ? Are you sure it's that program? I do not see how it could have printed "you test test it on your computer1"?

Comment: There are [very strict rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11675040/does-linux-allow-any-system-call-to-be-made-from-signal-handlers) about what you can do in a signal handler. Calling `printf` is not allowed.

Comment: the website reminders me that my submission are mostly code. 

so....

Comment: `wait()` is also not allowed in a signal handler

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the supposted output from the OPs program cannot be obtained from the OPs  program

Comment: A more simple description will be blocked by the submission.

Comment: Why can not you rethink the submission mechanism?