# Linking to multiple libraries, one of which wraps a set of system calls

Tags: c, linux, linker, posix, ld

So this is the scenario that I'm looking at:

I have 3 libraries - A, B and C.

- Library A implements function `foo()` and exposes it as an API.
- Function `foo()` calls the POSIX `write()` call to write some data.
- Library B writes a wrapper to the `write()` glibc call using the linker -wrap option.
- Library C links to both A and B.

Any `write()` call that the library C makes will get intercepted by the wrapper
library B. But, my question is, if library C calls `foo()`, will the `write()` call inside foo() get intercepted by B?

Comment: Try to write the code and look what happens, thats what i would do.

Comment: The glibc `write` function is a wrapper to the real system call.

Comment: Thank you, @JonathanCruz. These were hypothetical libraries I was talking about, and the behavior of the wrapper library in such a scenario would have been a deciding factor to see if I should go about writing it. However, I am now working on a smaller test case and now. I just thought turning to stackoverflow might give a quicker response :)

Comment: OMG. A good question on SO. Upvoted.

Comment: Thank you, @BasileStarynkevitch. Again, `write()` was just an example that I brought up. I'm curious about the behavior of a wrapper to any system function, say `bar()`.

Comment: Do you have access to the source code of your libraries? Are you expecting malicious behavior somewhere? Don't forget that a library could do a `write` syscall *without calling* any function (in particular the `write` function from Glibc wrapping the `write(2)` syscall) -e.g. just by a clever `asm` sequence using `sysenter`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11609768/841108

Comment: I do have access to the libraries that are in question. I am more concerned with the functionality than malicious behavior. In fact, I am looking for a solution in such a way that the function calls inside library A also get intercepted.

Comment: Also, I'm concerned only with C-level wrappers, and not wrappers to syscalls. I should reword my question, thank you! I apologize if that caused any confusion.

Comment: Actually, the answer to your question does not depend on `write` being a syscall wrapper. The linker (both the compile-time `ld` and the dynamic runtime `ld.so`) only works on *names* (symbols) and relocations (i.e. symbol occurrences).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `A` is linked with `-wrap=write`, `foo` will call the wrapper. If it's not, it won't.

The same is true about calls to `write` in `C`. There's no difference whatsoever between `A` and `C` as far as calling `write` is concerned.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I wanted to know!